# set index for specified rows in pandas and pass the data in json format

Tags: python, pandas

I have come across a problem in pandas which goes as follows

Have look at the attached jpg[image: dgr]

I need to make it in Pandas data frame and the entire data to be processed in the form of JSON.

Been trying but not getting the proper output/json format for UI purpose.

Though good at pandas, couldn't map X-Total, Y-total, Z-Total in proper indices.
Your suggestions would help me a lot.TIA

Comment: Hi RSK RAO, welcome on SO.Please take to some to read this and adjust your question accordingly [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide sample input and sample output with proof of trial code.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Those  numbers(1,2,3,4...5,5,6,7,8...) in the image are inputs.